# Which way is better while Injecting mapper interface with MyBatis-Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, mybatis

I was wondering what is the difference between injecting mapper interface via constructor argument and via property.

Code snippets are in below:

### **Via Constructor Argument**

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.example.mybatis.SomeMapper"/>
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="ServiceImpl" class="com.example.service.SomeServiceImpl">
  <constructor-arg ref="mapper"/>
</bean>
```

**Java**

```
public class SomeServiceImpl { 
  private final SomeMapper mapper;

  public SafeBoxDao(SomeMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }
}
```

### **Via Property**

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.example.mybatis.SomeMapper"/>
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="ServiceImpl" class="com.example.service.SomeServiceImpl">
  <property name="mapperInstance" ref="mapper" />
</bean>
```

**Java**

```
public class SomeServiceImpl {
  private SomeMapper mapper;

  public SafeBoxDao() {
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  public void setMapper(SomeMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }
}
```

Is there any difference, or it is just the different ways to inject mappers?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking (i.e. not limited to your question) Constructor injection is better, given it would be container agnostic. So even if you move from spring (unlikely in your case, given dependency on spring-mybatis module) to say CDI, you dont have to worry about mappers being injected correctly.

While strictly speaking in context of Spring as container, I'd prefer setter injection given following advice on Spring Docs.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-setter-injection

> The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it
>   enables one to implement application components as immutable objects
>   and to ensure that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore
>   constructor-injected components are always returned to client
>   (calling) code in a fully initialized state. As a side note, a large
>   number of constructor arguments is a bad code smell, implying that the
>   class likely has too many responsibilities and should be refactored to
>   better address proper separation of concerns.